# How to count occurrences in Django query and return list with attribute

Tags: django

I want to run a query, and return a list containing unique object name and their frequency. I have come across a few posts explaining this, but can't seem to fund one that utilizes the object name attribute. for example:

```
powderList = Build.objects.values('powder').annotate(total_count=Count('powder')).order_by('total_count')
```

returns:

```
{'powder': None, 'total_count': 0}, {'powder': 1, 'total_count': 2}, {'powder': 2, 'total_count': 2}
```

Which is very close to what I want, however this is displaying the `id` of `powder`. I would like to access an attribute of powder (`powder.name`) so that it would output instead:

```
{'powder': None, 'total_count': 0}, {'powder': Titanium, 'total_count': 2}, {'powder': Steel, 'total_count': 2}
```

I have tried:

```
powderList = Build.objects.values('powder.name').annotate(total_count=Count('powder')).order_by('total_count')

powderList = Build.objects.values('powder').annotate(total_count=Count('powder.name')).order_by('total_count')
```

My next plan is to use a `for loop` to iterate over the dict and find the name using the id, but this will be hitting the database every time. Is there a more efficient proper way to do this?

My models look like this:

```
class Build(models.Model): #(DMLS)
    PSScustomer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plannedAuthor =  models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,related_name='+',blank=True, null= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    powder =  models.ForeignKey('Powder', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Powder(models.Model):
    PSScustomer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this,

```
powderList = Build.objects.values('powder__name').annotate(total_count=Count('powder')).order_by('total_count')
```